# Using loader in a page??? NO jQuery pls?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

Pls see my prev. ques too. Pretty much the same:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595283/changes-to-page-when-using-loader

Now in response to the only comment i got, i did a bit of research on my own. I found a cool page :-https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

After reading a bit on that page, and the things mentioned in the comment by himanshu, here's what i got :-

HTML :

```
<body onload=" setTimeout(work, 2000)" >

<div class = circle ></div>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div id = test>
    8et 84yutreuty8e45 84 eyt84
</div>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">


.circle {
    border: 5px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-top:5px solid blue; 
    animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
    opacity: 1;

}

.circle.awesome {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 5s;
}


@keyframes rotate {
    0%{transform:rotate(0deg);}

    100%{transform: rotate(360deg);}

}



</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var web = document.getElementByClassName("circle")[0] ;

function work () {

     test.innerHTML = ("pppppppppppppppppppp");
     web.classList.add('awesome') ;
}



</script>
```

However, something seems to go wrong.

The text changes, but the opacity doesn't.
Pls tell me whats wrong. My guess is that the anmations and the transitions sort of fight with each other, with the animation not allowing the transition to work. However, if that's the case, i can't seem to figure a way around.

Also, what's the use of `[0]` in the line :-

```
 var web = document.getElementByClassName("circle")[0] ;
```

Also, it would be really helpful if you could give some hints as to how to proceed with doing the rest of the things i have mentioned in the question (link above).That would save me asking further questions in case i hit a roadblock. :D

P.S : Pls refrain from using jQuery. Don't know it yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changes to page when using loader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595283/changes-to-page-when-using-loader)

Comment: Your question _now_ seems to be "how do I use getElementByClassName?" - the backstory to why you're asking that isn't particularly relevant.

Comment: As pointed out it was caused by the typo `getElementByClassName`. Here you can see it working: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/gzLLv45s/

Comment: @thepio This doesn't seem to work in chrome??

Comment: @Pranav I'm using Chrome and it works for me :o

Comment: Can you try with adding the `-webkit-` prefix to it? https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/e8950h4h/

Comment: @thepio it works now even without the `-webkit-` prefix. In the end, i had to change the position of javascript from inside the head tag to defining a script tag within body itself, as in your fiddle. Any idea why thats so??

Comment: Oh I didn't even realize you had it like that. Well it might be that the script was trying to look for the div with a circle class before it was even rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName`. Probably that's where your error comes from.